# Argument labels '(xml:, url:, encoding:, option:)' do not match any available overloads

Tags: swift3

Went from Swift 2.2 to Swift 3 and now I've gotten stuck in this part of my code:

```
public func HTML(_ html: String, url: String?, encoding: String.Encoding, option: ParseOption = kDefaultHtmlParseOption) -> HTMLDocument? {
    switch option {
    case .htmlParseUseLibxml(let opt):
        return libxmlHTMLDocument(html: html, url: url, encoding: encoding, option: opt.rawValue)
    default:
        return nil
    }
}
public func HTML(_ html: String, encoding: String.Encoding, option: ParseOption = kDefaultHtmlParseOption) -> HTMLDocument? {
    return HTML(html: html, url: nil, encoding: encoding, option: option)
}
```

I have various instances where an error appears on line 2 stating:

> Argument labels '(html:, url:, encoding:, option:)' do not match any
>   available overloads

This is another instance of a similar issue:

```
public func XML(_ xml: String, url: String?, encoding: String.Encoding, option: ParseOption = kDefaultXmlParseOption) -> XMLDocument? {
    switch option {
    case .xmlParseUseLibxml(let opt):
        return libxmlXMLDocument(xml: xml, url: url, encoding: encoding, option: opt.rawValue)
    default:
        return nil
    }
}
public func XML(_ url: URL, encoding: String.Encoding, option: ParseOption = kDefaultXmlParseOption) -> XMLDocument? {
    if let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url) {
        return XML(xml: data, url: url.absoluteString, encoding: encoding, option: option)
    }
    return nil
}
```

Error:

> Argument labels '(xml:, url:, encoding:, option:)' do not match any
>   available overloads

I'd greatly appreciate any help on how to solve this, thanks.

Comment: Is it xml or html ?

Comment: Update your question with the methods you are attempting to call (the ones causing the errors).

Comment: Just did. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `_` in the parameter declaration means that the parameter does not have an argument label so you don't put the label for the argument when calling the method.

Your code should be:

```
public func HTML(_ html: String, url: String?, encoding: String.Encoding, option: ParseOption = kDefaultHtmlParseOption) -> HTMLDocument? {
    switch option {
    case .htmlParseUseLibxml(let opt):
        return libxmlHTMLDocument(html: html, url: url, encoding: encoding, option: opt.rawValue)
    default:
        return nil
    }
}
public func HTML(_ html: String, encoding: String.Encoding, option: ParseOption = kDefaultHtmlParseOption) -> HTMLDocument? {
    // Change the line below:
    return HTML(html, url: nil, encoding: encoding, option: option)
}
```

The XML version is basically the same.